# Reading bytes from file

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write huffman decompress, I have a function which is trying to read byte by byte whole compressed file, but I have a problem it reads only around 150 firsts bytes and rest are skipped I cant understand why.

Here's the function:

```
public static StringBuilder odczytBajtowy(string nazwa)
    {
        FileStream plik = null;
        StringBuilder dane = new StringBuilder("");
        try
        {
            plik = new FileStream(@nazwa, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            int w;
            int n = 0;
            do
            {
                n++;
                w = plik.ReadByte();

                if (w != -1)
                    dane.Append(StringHelp.Reverse(Convert.ToString((byte)w,2).PadLeft(8, '0')));
            }
            while ((w > 0));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Brak pliku {0}", nazwa);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (plik != null)
            {
                plik.Close();
            }
        }

        return dane;
    }
```

It looks like the function reads EOF before the file is really at the end. I know there is no EOF somewhere between bytes because I'm writing there only byte values.

Comment: coudl it be becouse in while condition i have w > 0 instead of >= ?

Comment: Yes, a 0 in the file will end your while loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while condition is incorrect : it should read `while (w != -1)`, so you stop looping through read bytes as soon as a zero byte is found, rather than at the end-of-file.

Answer (score 2):

```
while ((w > 0));
```

This will stop when it reaches a 0. Change this to

```
while ((w >= 0));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably hitting a zero byte.

Change your while loop to include 0:

```
while ((w >= 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

while ((w > 0));

It should be:

while ((w != -1));

Because it's likely your file has a 0 in it.